# Auto update version numbers (C++ / C#) in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2005, build-automation, versioning

I want to automate part of my build process, such that I can click a button (or run a program, etc.) that will automatically update the version numbers in all C++ and C# projects within my solution.

All my version numbers are date based, so it will be easy to create.

How do I go about tackling this? Does Visual Studio have any in-built functionality to allow this, or if not, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest this tool

[Versioning Controlled Build](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5851/Versioning-Controlled-Build)

I have used it for many years now and it let you control every aspect of the versioning problem

Answer (score 0):

It can but only for strong assemblies (in the case just add asterisk [*] to number which you want to auto increment) If yours is not such a case you could try [ProjectBuildCounter](http://build.codeplex.com/).

It is free, easy to use, standalone executable. You have to attach it to your project and - voila - versions are incremented on each build.

Could be used for as many projects as needed. You might [download nere](http://build.codeplex.com/). Usage info is [available here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuD7jpQmYck)